# How to remove all occurrences of a certain letter without advanced collections? (Python)

Tags: python

I've been working on this code for a while and I can't seem to figure it out. We're not allowed to use splices, .find(), .count(), or .replace(). I have to do it using a for loop, but can't seem to find the solution.
Current code looks like this:

```
def removeChar(word1, letter1):
    s1 =''
    length = len(word1)
    for i in range(length):
        if (letter1 in word1[i]):
            s1 = word1[i] 
    return s1
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to iterate over your string. Whenever you encounter a letter that *isn't* the letter you want to exclude, add it to a new string. If it *is*, ignore it. When the iteration is over, return the new string.

```
def removeChar(word1, letter1):
    new_string = ''
    for letter in word1:
        if (letter != letter1):
            new_string += letter
    return new_string
```

#### Examples

```
>>> removeChar('hello', 'o')
'hell'
>>> removeChar('hello', 'l')
'heo'
```

Comment: Thank you so much... Couldn't figure that out at all.

Comment: Nice answer! Couldn't get what OP was saying by advanced collections features ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough to do in one line:

```
new_word = ''.join(char for char in word if char != letter)
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way would be to use something like this:

```
word = "let's remove some letters from this string"
letter = 's'

print(''.join(word.split(letter)))
```

Explanation:

- `split(letter)` will split the input string into an list of strings using letter as separator
- then you use `''.join` to join all the elements of this list, this will produce the string without the char `letter`.
- `split` and `join` are basic operations on strings

**Output:**

```
python remove_letter.py
let' remove ome letter from thi tring
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
s1.extend([word[i]]))
```

this code will add a single letter of word to s1. Currently your code sets all of s1 to one letter of word